# Creating Route events in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, linear-referencing

In ArcGIS I have a set of routes, some of whose direction I change using the flip edit so that they are in the direction I require. I am able to make route event layers. However, why is it that after creating a route event layer, these routes whose direction was changed are found to be with their original direction.

workflow process is as follows; add autocad drawing to arcMap,edit properties of polyline features by setting layer=tracks; assign road codes to the tracks and create routes using roadcode attribute; edit the direction of the routes created;export as a layer; make route event layer with the exported layer using linear referencing tool and an excel table with road code attribute.

I need to have route events with the direction after flipping. How do I do this?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include precise details of your workflow, please?  My recollection is that it is possible to leave the underlying routes unflipped while flipping the events that reference them.